# python raises syntax error when computing eigenvalues of a general matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I intend to plot the eigenvalue(s) of the Jacobian matrix over the range -3 ≤ μ ≤ 3 in 0.1 steps in Python.

Please see my code below:

```
import numpy as np

mu = np.arange(-3,3,0.1)

J =([[0, 1],
 [-1, -mu]])

assign lambda 

lambda = np.linalg.eigvals(J)

print(lambda)
```

Then this showed up: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax," and it's pointing at "lambda" in the "assign lambda" line.

Then my code for plotting is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.figure()
plt.plot(mu, lambda, 's') 
plt.xlabel('mu')
plt.ylabel('Eigenvalue')
plt.show()
```

Another "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" showed up, pointing at the "lambda" in this section.

I've also tried to get rid of the "assign lambda" line but still didn't work. This kind of error has happened before when I try to define a function or parameter.

Could anyone please take a look and help me? I am very new to Python.

Thank you very much!

Comment: lambda is a keyword in Python. Please use a different name for `lambda`. Also assign is not a keyword.

Comment: @Mudits Thank you for pointing that out! but i've tried other names, same syntax error message showed up as well.

Comment: What is `assign lambda` supposed to do? Should that be a comment of what the following line is supposed to do?

Comment: you wanted to assign the value of `lambda` to a variable that is not the way.. you should do  simple like `value=myvar`

Comment: Your J is 2X2 so you will have 2 eigen vectors. If x axis is mu then how do you plan to plot  2 eigen vectors for that corresponding J (with corresponding mu)

Comment: @tobias_k when I don't have this line there a value error message shows up: "setting an array element with a sequence."

Comment: BTW, you can just do `λ = np.linalg.eigvals(J)` (but you probably shouldn't)

Comment: @mujjiga mu is in between -3 and 3 with 0.1 steps. eigenvalues are expressed in terms of mu. so my x-axis will be mu from -3 to 3, y-axis will be the eigenvalues that are calculated based on each mu value.

Comment: Maybe, but a `ValueError` means that your code at least compiles (other than with a Syntax Error); the next step will by why you get _that_ error.

Comment: @czhang75: For each mu, you have two eigen values. So you need to plot both. Some of them are imaginary

Comment: @tobias_k the same error message showed up.

Comment: @Bazingaa yes, is my code for plotting alright?

Comment: @tobias_k Do you know how to fix the value error? "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence." Thank you!

Comment: Thank you all so much for your comments! You all have been super helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
mu = np.arange(-3,3,0.1)
e = list()

for m in mu:
    J = np.array([[0, 1], [-1, -m]])
    e.append(np.linalg.eigvals(J))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(mu, e, 's') 
plt.xlabel('mu')
plt.ylabel('Eigenvalue')
plt.show()
```

- For each mu create a `J`
- Calculate the eigen vectors for `J` and save it in list `e`
- Finally plot eigen vectors in `e` with respect to `mu`

Comment: Thank you so much! so creating a list for the desired outputs can avoid having syntax error?

Comment: @czhang75 No, not using `lambda` as a variable name fixed the syntax error, and the `for m in mu` loop fixed the value error.

Comment: @tobias_k I see! so "for m in mu" is what we should be using to define parameters?

Comment: @tobias_k also, how did you type the gray box in the comment?

Comment: @czhang75 No offence, but you should try some basic Python tutorial. The `for` thing is a "loop", and you "define parameters" (or variables) just with `x = ...`, but `x` can not be a keyword (like `def`, `for`, or `lambda`). And `assign ...` is just not valid syntax.

Comment: @czhang75 same question i had till few days back :) put the text in between `

Comment: @tobias_k Thank you!

Comment: @mujjiga `Thank you!:)`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to vectorise `mu` which is not the correct way in your code. You can simply use a for loop

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

mu = np.arange(-3,3,0.1)
lambda_list = []

for i in mu:
    J = [[0, 1],[-1, -i]]
    lambda_list.append(np.linalg.eigvals(J))

lambda_list = np.array(lambda_list)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(mu, lambda_list[:, 0], '-r', label='Eigenvalue 1') 
plt.plot(mu, lambda_list[:, 1], '-b', label='Eigenvalue 2') 
plt.xlabel('mu')
plt.ylabel('Eigenvalue')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! There is red banner saying that "ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)" but i have plot. is this alright?

Comment: That warning is because you have imaginary values as your eigenvalues. You should look into your values if they make sense

Comment: I've done the calculations by hand. It makes sense to have complex results here. Thank you very much!